# Can not split or substr a string retrieved from a PlayStore product on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have an Ionic 2 app that allow users to consume subscriptions.

I need to cut the price that I retrieve from Play store for each product because Play store return me the price in a string format and not separately.

The plugin inAppPurchases have a `getProducts()` method that receive an string array with the product id's that you need retrieve, and returns an object array with the products:

```
this.inAppPurchase.getProducts(this.productIds)
            .then((products) => {
            });
```

Well that products are objects which have an attribute called price. This price is not a number, is a string. So I need to separate the price of the currency, and the unique way to do this is cutting these string in the first space that they have.

But the problem is so rare, because if I attempt to cut the string that Google play retrieves me, I can't!:

```
let productPrice = retrievedProduct.price; //this is the attribute price from each product object

console.log("From play store: " + productPrice); //From play store: US$ 35,88
console.log("Type: " + typeof productPrice); //Type: string
console.log("Length: " + productPrice.length); //Length: 9  
let priceWithoutCurrency = productPrice.substr(productPrice.indexOf(' ') + 1);
console.log("Delete currency with google play product: " + priceWithoutCurrency); //Delete currency with google play product: US$ 35,88

let retrievedPrice = "US$ 35,88";
let priceWithoutCurrency2 = retrievedPrice.substr(retrievedPrice.indexOf(' ') + 1);
console.log("----------------");
console.log("From mock: " + retrievedPrice); //From mock: US$ 35,88  
console.log("Type: " + typeof retrievedPrice); // Type: string  
console.log("Length: " + retrievedPrice.length); //Length: 9
console.log("Delete currency with mock price: " + priceWithoutCurrency2); //Delete currency with mock price: 35,88
```

You can see that both strings are equal, and it's not working.
Anyone knows why it's happening?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: How does retrievedProduct.price look like?

Comment: Looks like "US$ 38,55" but it depende of the language of the device, for example in another device it looks like "$ 38,55" , always with a space between currency and amount

Comment: Instead of substr, maybe try using string.splice(" ")? If there always a space between currency and amount. Then you can just retrieve the amount as string[1].